# php5-fpm not working without restarting twice every time

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx, php-fpm

I'm on ubuntu (10.10) and I've got php5-fpm installed. Whenever I restart it, I get no errors, just a successful restart message. But it's not really working (I only know this because php pages get an error (502 bad gateway if I recall correctly). If I restart again it works just fine. So every time I need to restart I just do it quickly twice. The problem is I want to be able to restart an entire server and have it working without having to go restart php5-fpm again.

How can I figure out this problem? What logs should I look at? Anyone else had similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

/var/log/php5-fpm.log would be a good start.
You might want to check out the question and the suggestions at [PHP-FASTCGI hangs with nginx, is there a better solution to this problem?](https://serverfault.com/questions/261150/php-fastcgi-hangs-with-nginx-is-there-a-better-solution-to-this-problem/278585#278585), which describes a php-fpm that stops responding.

Comment: Nothing suspicious in the php fpm log (just normal messages). The question you suggested is different than php5-fpm.